# Using where clause with Union in GoogleSql Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to union two tables comparing a matching field but I am receving the following error:-
"SQL_ANALYSIS_ERROR: Unrecognized name: t2 (Line: 87, Column: 121)"
where t2 is renamed for my second table

Here is my code:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_1 OPTIONS (
  quota_accounting_owner='sxxx@gmail.com')
AS 
  SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(fate_result), CAST(fate_result AS STRING) AS fate_result FROM table_1 AS t1 WHERE t2.e_id <> t1.e_id
  UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT * EXCEPT(fate_result), CAST(fate_result AS STRING) AS fate_result FROM table_2 AS t2
    );
```

Comment: ```FROM table_1 as t1 WHERE t2. ...``` in the first statement of your UNION is not permitted because ```t2``` is not defined in this statement. ```UNION``` is more or less a concatenation of the results of 2 statements but these statements are independant

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! what would be the work around for my condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to select only the rows of `table_1` that don't have a matching `e_id` in `table_2`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_1 OPTIONS (
  quota_accounting_owner='sxxx@gmail.com')
AS 
  SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(fate_result), CAST(fate_result AS STRING) AS fate_result
    FROM table_1 AS t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM table_2 AS t2
       WHERE t2.e_id = t1.e_id
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT * EXCEPT(fate_result), CAST(fate_result AS STRING) AS fate_result
    FROM table_2 AS t2
  );
```

**EDIT** NOT EXISTS would be the right choice for standard SQL but seeing the comments below, here it throws an error. so NOT IN may be better

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_1 OPTIONS (
  quota_accounting_owner='sxxx@gmail.com')
AS 
  SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(fate_result), CAST(fate_result AS STRING) AS fate_result
    FROM table_1 AS t1
    WHERE t1.e_id NOT IN (
       SELECT t2.ed_id
       FROM table_2 AS t2
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT * EXCEPT(fate_result), CAST(fate_result AS STRING) AS fate_result
    FROM table_2 AS t2
  );
```

Comment: Just a confusion you have used `t2.e_id = t1.e_id` instead of what I have used `t2.e_id <> t1.e_id` is this intended. or goes with your code.

Comment: Now I am receiving this error `The FROM clause of a subquery expression ('SELECT 1
       FROM table_2 AS t2
       WHERE t2.e_id = t1.e_id') contains a reference to a table that is not an array or repeated field derived from a table in the enclosing query`

Comment: This is not a confusion : you want to remove from t1 the rows of t2 where t1.e_id = t2.e_id.  I can't find any example with NOT EXISTS although the keyword is documented by Google. May be it is better use NOT IN. I edit with NOT IN

Comment: NOT IN did the job Thank you very much.